# I wan to create MS excel file by input some words in MS word files to MS excel file through Python

Tags: python-3.x

That is simple scenario as follows but it's not easy to me. 
Please let me know how to design the procedures by Python code.

1) open MS word file (source file)
2) search specific words (on condition)
3) write words searched to MS excel file

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily adaptable to do what you want:

```
# 1. Open MS Word file with python-docx
#  https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html
from docx import Document

doc = Document('document.docx')


# 2. Search for specific words

specific_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

search_results = {}

for count, word in enumerate(specific_words):
    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        if word in p.text:
            search_results[count] = {'Word':word, 'Text':p.text}


# 3. Write results to Excel file.

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(search_results, index = ['Word', 'Text']).transpose()

df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```